# Joining 3 tables same id different and same descriptions

Tags: mysql, join

I am attempting to join three tables together.  Tables A, B, and C. 
The ID is the same for all three tables.

Each table has a field descriptions. ID 1 with description Name in Table A should be ID 1 with description Name in table B. Likewise for Table C it should be ID1 with description Name.

But some of the ID shows ID1 description Nameblank. I want to display SAME – A if it has the same value as B or C. And if all three are the same I do not want it displayed.
For example:

Table A

```
ID      Description

1       Name

2       Noname

3       Namea
```

Table B

```
ID      Description

1       Nameblank

2       Noname

3       Nameb
```

Table C

```
ID      Description

1       Name

2       Noname

3       Namec
```

Result

```
ID  A Description   B Description   C Description

1       |   Name  |  Namea        |   Nameblank

3       |       Nameb|  SAME – A      |    Namec
```

I haven't joined three tables before and I am confused. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    A.ID as 'ID',
    A.Description as 'A Description',
    B.Description as 'B Description',
    C.Description as 'C Description'
From
    TableA A
        INNER JOIN
    TableB B ON (A.ID = B.ID)
        INNER JOIN
    TableC C ON (A.ID = C.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TABLEA.ID, 
       TABLEA.Description as ADescription,

       CASE WHEN TABLEA.Description=TABLEB.Description THEN 'SAME - A'
                  ELSE TABLEB.Description
       END as BDescription,

       CASE WHEN TABLEA.Description=TABLEC.Description THEN 'SAME - A'
                  ELSE TABLEC.Description
       END as CDescription

from TABLEA
JOIN TABLEB on TABLEA.id=TABLEB.id
JOIN TABLEC on TABLEC.id=TABLEC.id

Where TABLEA.Description<>TABLEB.Description
      or 
      TABLEB.Description<>TABLEC.Description
ORDER BY TABLEA.id
```